# How to get collection of all active wpf windows (multithreading) if Apllication.Current is NULL?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

In my project i programmatically create couple wpf windows from class in different threads. In one of this wpf windows code (xaml.cs) I want to get all active wpf windows using `System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows` but `System.Windows.Application.Current` is `Null`. How can i get this collection and is it really possible?

Comment: You can't create different windows in different threads to begin with, unless you create a new message pump. There's no reason to do so though. WPF applications worki with a single UI thread just fine by performing non-UI operations on different threads

Comment: Why are you trying to windows from multiple threads? What is the *actual* problem you want to solve?

Comment: Of course it's possible.  Just switch to each thread you made that created a window and call Application.Current.Windows from inside that thread.  Since you cannot interact with those windows from outside their creating thread anyway, you have to do this already, right?  Think of it as saving you a Dispatcher call later.

Comment: You could add a reference to each window to a static list when you create them.

Comment: @mm8 it would be better to just keep track of the Application instances as each is created, than to duplicate the Window tracking framework.

Comment: @hoodaticus: Why would this be better? There may be just be one Application but several windows running on different threads.

Comment: @mm8 - you're right it wouldn't be better.  I had assumed there were multiple application instances.  Apparently he doesn't have any at all.

Comment: It's a really bad idea to use multiple UI threads for WPF. Once you have a reference to one of these other windows, created on some other thread. Then what? What do you intend doing with it? Just shutting one down is non trivial http://reedcopsey.com/2011/11/28/launching-a-wpf-window-in-a-separate-thread-part-1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create windows on different threads for whatever reasons, you should keep track of them yourself. You could for example add them to a static collection that may be accessible from all threads, e.g.:

```
public class ApplicationService
{
    private readonly List<Window> _windows = new List<Window>();

    public IEnumerable<Window> Windows => _windows;

    public void Add(Window window)
    {
        if (window == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(window));

        lock (_windows)
        {
            window.Closed += Window_Closed;
            _windows.Add(window);
        }
    }

    private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Window window = (Window)sender;
        lock (_windows)
        {
            window.Closed -= Window_Closed;
            _windows.Remove(window);
        }
    }
}
```

The `Application.Current.Windows` collection doesn't keep track of windows created on any other thread than the app's dispatcher thread.